# What is wrong with this break statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to break if the topic was created today, and only continue if it's from yesterday or older.

```
break if topic.created_at.to_i > Time.now.beginning_of_day.to_i
```

Comment: You should tell us a bit more. What do the two sides of the GT sign return?

Comment: I guess do they even return what you would expect? Obviously, the .to_i is an int. But, can you tell us why you want to know what is wrong with it? Do the int values make sense? Is it always failing to break?

Comment: If you are getting error messages, please include them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting the time to to_i, just compare the values, i.e:
topic.created_at > Time.now.beginning_of_day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
break if topic.created_at.today?
```

Comment: Okay then its not a problem of demitering time stuff. Pleas describe in which context you are using this peace of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use abort

```
abort("Nothing more should happen") unless condition
```